# Ionic 4: loading.present is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic 4, getting an error while using the loader
`loading.present is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
const loading =  this.loadingController.create({
  message: 'Loading',
});

loading.present();
```

Comment: I think Ionic 4 migration guide covers this in detail as well.

Comment: Still, people miss it and create the git issues

Answer (score 9):

This is because loadingController.create() is an asynchronous method and before you get the instance of HTMLIonLoadingElement in variable `loading`,
you are calling the `loading/present()` which is undefined for the moment.

So you need to wait until you get the instance of HTMLIonLoadingElement while calling `loadingController.create()`

How to solve it: Simple use aync/await

```
const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
  message: 'Loading',
});
loading.present();
```

See we used `await` just after the = operator. So it makes sure next line to be executed only when call to `loadingController.create` is complete and variable loading is initialized.

> NOTE: Don't forget to add async keyword to the function inside which you are using the loader code, as we are using await.